# Is it possible to restrict the group to have reader access at container level in azure?

Tags: azure, rbac, azure-rbac

If a group has contributor access at subscription level, is it possible to restrict the group to have reader access at container level in azure?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51283760/1658906

Comment: If that group has contributor access at the subscription level, it will inherit to the container also even if you assign the reader access on the container as well.

Create a custom role with the necessary permissions, excluding the permission for the storage container. Assign the same custom role to the groups who need contributor access without access to the storage container.

Comment: You can also use azure policy to restrict only azure container level.